# Meaning of mass-deformation in string theory and quantum field theories

Tags: mass, field-theory, supersymmetry, chern-simons-theory

I was reading some papers in the [ABJM theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABJM_superconformal_field_theory). I keep reading the term mass deformation but am not sure what it really means. I think the papers assume the reader is familiar with the term. Example paper: http://inspirehep.net/record/1300553?ln=en
What is mass deformation?

Answer (score 1):

In general it is simply an addition (i.e. a deformation) of a mass term to the (super)potential.